Updating drop down with new code when adding new code in another component
I am very new to angular. I have a component named code.ts which has a single drop down and a Add New button. I have another component with the form to add a new code. I want to re-load codes in the drop down when I add a new code. I tried to follow another thread I found here How to refresh a component from another in angular? but I cannot make it to work. This is what I have in the code component:
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, numberAttribute } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { CodeNewComponent } from './code-new/code-new.component';


import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IUITKSelectItemProps, UITKSelectModule, UITKTableDataSource, UITKTableModule } from '@uitk/angular';
import { CodeService } from './code.service';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonService } from '../shared/common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgFor, FormsModule, RouterModule, UITKSelectModule, CodeNewComponent],
  templateUrl: './code.component.html',
  styleUrl: './code.component.css'
})
export class CodeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  messageReceived: any;
  private subscriptionName: Subscription = new Subscription(); //important to create a subscription


  constructor(private _codeService: CodeService, 
    private _service: CommonService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router)
  {    
    if(this.tableGroupCode === undefined){
      this.tableGroupCode = {id: '', label:'', value:''};
    }
    this.subscriptionName= this._service.getUpdate().subscribe
    (message => { //message contains the data sent from service
    this.messageReceived = message;
    if (message=='New Code added'){
        this.getCodes(); 
       }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCodes();
   }
   
   getCodes() : void
   {
    console.log('Calling this.GetCodes()');
    this._codeService.GetCodes().then(
      (codes) => {
       
          for(let entity of codes){
            this.codes.push({id: entity.Code, label: entity.Description, value: entity.Code});
          }
      },
  );
   }
   codes: IUITKSelectItemProps[] = [];
   tableGroupCode: IUITKSelectItemProps|undefined;;

   onSelect(groupCode: IUITKSelectItemProps|undefined){
    // alert(groupCode);
    if(groupCode !== undefined && groupCode?.id!='')
      {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedTableGroupCode', groupCode?.id??"");
      }
    //  console.log(localStorage.getItem('selectedTableGroupCode'));
   }

   ngOnDestroy() { // It's a good practice to unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscriptionName.unsubscribe();
}
}

And this is what I have in the Submit button code for the code-new component:
  onSubmit() {
    const formValue = this.codeForm.getRawValue();
    this.newCode = new Code(
    'TableGroupCode',
    formValue.codeControl!,  
    formValue.descriptionControl!,
    'A'
    );

    this._codeService.InsertUpdateCode(this.newCode).then(
      (code) => {
          this.returnedCode = code;
      },
    );
    //alert("Table Group Code saved successfully!"); // TODO change to nice modal
    //this.alertConfig.id = 'info-alert' + this.count++;
    this.alertConfig.content = 'Table Group Code saved successfully!';
   // this.codeAdded.emit({id: formValue.codeControl!, label: formValue.descriptionControl!});
    this.alertService.setContainerConfig({position: 'top-right'});
    this.alertService.showNotification(this.alertConfig);
    this._service.sendUpdate('New Code added');    
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
   
  }

What should I do to achieve this simple task of re-loading the list of codes?
Thanks in advance

Angular is not meant to reload components, you should just set the data to what you want it to be, and the dropdown should update. It's more common to have a BehaviorSubject in your service and update that one (and expose using asObservable).

Can you please show an example? I've been reading a lot about Subjects and Observables, but I still don't understand. I need a sample I can use.

A very simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts

Thanks so much. With the help of my colleague we went with the @Output and event emitter option, but I like this sample and it may come handy too.

Do you think having two @Output events may cause issue? My current code in Submit button:    this._codeService.InsertUpdateCode(this.newCode).subscribe(
(code) => {
this.returnedCode = code;
if (code) {
this.updateParentCodeList.emit(true);
}
}
)
 ;
this.toggleFormVisibility.emit(false);
this.alertConfig.content = 'Table Group Code saved successfully!';

this.alertService.setContainerConfig({position: 'top-right'});
this.alertService.showNotification(this.alertConfig);


The toggleFormVisibility event fires and parent component is notified and reacts, but the updateParentCodeList does not execute code on the parent component. When I examine it in debugger I'm seeing current observables empty array

This is what I see in debugger and don't know how to go from there:
closed
:
false
currentObservers
:
null
destroyRef
:
NodeInjectorDestroyRef {_lView: Array(37)}
hasError
:
false
isStopped
:
false
observers
:
[]
thrownError
:
null
__isAsync
:
false
observed
:
(...)
[[Prototype]]
:
Subject2
